# HTML Placeholder Standards

Tags: html, asp.net, forms, web

I am creating a form wizard in .net and part of the requirement is to use placeholder text in the form fields along with labels beside the form.

For example I have

`@Html.LabelFor(model => model.FullName)
 @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.FullName, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Full Name" })`

or for the hint I can use `placeholder = "John Doe"` or `placeholder = "ex: John Doe"`

Since I am using a wizard, the form has approx 50 fields over multiple tabs for data entry such that using placeholders for every field may not always clarify what is needed in which case I would redundantly put the name of the form label for consistency. Because of this I am rethinking using placeholders at all. I worry that the form will be harder to look at given the amount of fields and possible uselessness / extra clutter of placeholder text.

Is there a standard in place for what is appropriate for placeholder text given different form designs?

Is there an accepted use for when it is and isn't okay to use placeholder text?

Comment: You might find the [HTML5 specification for the `placeholder` attribute](https://www.w3.org/TR/html/sec-forms.html#the-placeholder-attribute) informative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More information can be found in this UX discussion [here](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/83380/placeholders-with-the-same-text-as-the-label-good-practice)

Via [W3](https://www.w3.org/TR/html/sec-forms.html#the-placeholder-attribute) describes as a short hint.

> The placeholder attribute represents a short hint (a word or short phrase) intended to aid the user with data entry when the control has no value. A hint could be a sample value or a brief description of the expected format. The attribute, if specified, must have a value that contains no U+000A LINE FEED (LF) or U+000D CARRIAGE RETURN (CR) characters.

See Also: [Placeholders in Form Fields Can Be Harmful](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/form-design-placeholders/)

Ignore the word [harmful](http://meyerweb.com/eric/comment/chech.html) and it's a normal very normal article backed in some part by data:

> In-context descriptions or hints can help clarify what goes inside each form field, and therefore improve completion and conversion rates. Placeholder text, located inside a form field, is an additional hint, description, or example of the information required for a particular field. These hints typically disappear when the user types in the field.

The article also suggests placing the hints outside the form field if it's warranted, or if space is available.

> Ultimately, adaptive placeholders do offer a better user experience than the label as a placeholder. But if you have the screen space, placing the label and hint outside the field is still the best way to go.